# Isblank formula with a cell range

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to get the result as Yes or No based on the empty cells in the given cellrange.

=iferror(if(isblank(FJ11:GI11),"YES","NO"))

Please help...

If its a single cell, its working fine but not working with a cellrange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `COUNTA` or `COUNTBLANK` functions.

```cpp
=IF(COUNTA(FJ11:GI11)=0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thank you so much as its working fine as intended.